# Pool of workers with Akka Streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

As described in [akka streams documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/stream/stream-cookbook.html#Balancing_jobs_to_a_fixed_pool_of_workers) I tried to create a pool of workers (flows):

```
def balancer[In, Out](worker: Flow[In, Out, NotUsed], workerCount: Int): Flow[In, Out, NotUsed] = {
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._

    Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
      val balancer = b.add(Balance[In](workerCount))
      val merge = b.add(Merge[Out](workerCount))

      for (_ <- 1 to workerCount) {
        balancer ~> worker ~> merge
      }
      FlowShape(balancer.in, merge.out)
    })
  }
```

then I used this function to run a flow in parallel:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val system = ActorSystem()
    implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer.create(system)

    val flow = Flow[Int].map(e => {
      println(e)
      Thread.sleep(1000) // 1 second
      e
    })

    Source(Range.apply(1, 10).toList)
      .via(balancer(flow, 3))
      .runForeach(e => {})
  }
```

I get the expected output `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9` but the numbers appear at a rate 1 per second (no parallelism). What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: what about execution context? If you are using a fixed sized thread pool with one this is normal

Comment: That means that the default context's size is 1? Could you please detail what is the preferred way to configure the execution context?

Comment: No default context is not fixed, you are probably importing global implicit context, which will depend on too much thing like version, you can try `implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))`

Comment: It's because of fusing. If you disable auto-fusing, it works. I haven't posted an answer because I can't find a way of configuring async boundaries correctly yet. I'm still investigating

Comment: @GiovanniCaporaletti you are absolutely right, without auto-fusing it works. But I cannot find a way to let auto-fusing enabled and just set the boundaries with `.async` to make it work. Hmm.. intersting.. i get **different results** without changing the code.

Comment: I put async boundaries literally everywhere and I got random parallelism (sometimes 1, sometimes 2 or 3 etc). Something's wrong O_o. @Mihai238 Ok you get the same too. Maybe we need to open an issue or ask on gitter

Comment: I've already created an issue: https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/20146

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Endre Varga pointed out, the flow itself should be marked with `.async`.

But even then, the behavior is not deterministic because the async stages have a default buffer size of 16 and the balancer might send all messages to the same worker.

As a result, `balancer ~> worker.async.addAttributes(Attributes.inputBuffer(1, 1)) ~> merge` would lead to the desired behavior.

For an answer given by a project member see:
https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/20146#issuecomment-201381356

Answer (score 3):

The docs in that section are outdated which will be fixed in the next release. Basically all you need is to call `.async` on the flow itself. By doing this, you kind-of draw a "box" around the flow (which you can imagine as a box with one input and output port) which will prevent fusing across that box. By doing this essentially all the workers will be on dedicated actors. The rest of the graph (the broadcast and merge stages) will share another actor (they will not run on separate actors, the async box only protects the flow, things outside will still be fused).

Comment: I believe that this is how it should be, but I also believe that this is not how it is. `for (i <- 1 to workerCount) { balancer ~> worker.async ~> merge }` does not seem to work.

Comment: As I noted in your ticket (and after playing around, I got confused myself) it turns out that the default buffer size for async stages is 16 and balance ends up sending all the messages to a single stage since it reports as still having buffer space. If you either send more messages (like 100) or set the buffer size of the worker stage to 1, you will see the desired results.

Comment: Yeah, right, also setting `waitForAllDownstreams = true` could help a bit with it. I think (I have not really checked it), what happens is that as you've said the first downstream reports, and all messages are being sent down to it. With `waitForAllDownstreams ` it seams the distribution is a bit better

Comment: Not just that but how fusing works: First, the first Request(16) message arrives to the fused island of merge+balance. Then the balance stage is pulled (which pulls the source of numbers, but let's ignore that) and pushes an element to the output port. Since there is demand left, and we have not processed the Request(16) from another source (we are still in the receive block of the previous!) it just pulls the balance again, which ferries a new element to the port again, and so on. Fusing has an upper limit on how much such synchronous steps are taken until suspension (a self-message).

Comment: In the next version (2.4.3) it will be possible to set the number of events a fused island makes via configuration. If this is set to one then again the expected behavior will happen. This is has performance effects though, so it is not recommended, but this completes the picture why the observed outcome happens.